# Is using jQuery the only way to make REST based crud UI inside spring boot app?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot

I don't want to use react or angular since they need to make a separate project .What I want to do is get json from rest controller and use it for async crud operation inside the same spring boot project .
I've been googling and I only found tutorials that use jQuery or old angular js

Comment: jQuery ajax wraps XMLHttpRequest, so there are native javascript methods you can use.  jquery just makes it a lot easier.   As noted in the answer below there's newer javascript methods (that copy jquery...).  As for "the only way" - there are probably many other libraries that wrap ajax calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native javascript fetch api to get or post data

```
fetch(url) // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
.then(function() {
// Your code for handling the data you get from the API
})
.catch(function() {
// This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
});
```

Comment: In-case anyone needs to check: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch